# Using external data in Trading View

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have developed an AI model using python that predicts the future price of crypto/stock. I would like to make use of the output of this model in Pine Script.

I was initially hoping that I would be able to make an API call to my model, but I quickly realized that Pine Script doesn't currently have a way to do that.

Is there currently a way I can access external data through Pine Script. If the answer is no, does anyone know if this is something that might be added in the future to Pine Script or if it's intentionally left out?

Comment: Reading through other threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930861/is-there-a-way-to-plot-values-from-a-google-sheets-workbook-to-tradingview-pines/64932245?r=SearchResults#64932245 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66356225/pine-script-external-data-alternative?r=SearchResults https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62994081/using-pine-script-is-it-possible-to-add-some-external-data-from-some-file-to-the?r=SearchResults